# Theorems on toric sections

Tags: solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

Do any theorems other than [Villarceau's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villarceau_circles) and closely related results say anything about intersections of planes with tori?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are looking for, but I've recently completed an article about toric sections, their equation and an unexpected relation with cone-cylinder intersections.

[The toric sections: a simple introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00803)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I had in mind was actually this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260202/jacobis-elliptic-functions-and-plane-sections-of-a-torus